# Three.js. PerspectiveCamera height position

Tags: javascript, three.js, camera, perspective

I can't find camera y position. I've played around with this numbers, but I didn't get the desired result:

```
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
camera.position.set(0, 4, 15);
camera.lookAt(0, 0.5, 0);
```

right now the camera is on this level:

[image]

the look level as a dog. I have to adjust it to look like a grown up. I have to see what is on the table.

@Marquizzo changed 4 to 12 `camera.position.set(0, 12, 15);`, it did the job, but still, the camera is looking from above downwards (looks like some 15°). I need the camera on the same height, but the sight has to be horizontal, like your eyes looking just forward:

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. The camera's y-position is 4 when you set it as `camera.position.set(0, 4, 15);` To move it above the table, try setting it to 8. If that's not the behavior you're experiencing, then you'll need to add more code to your question, perhaps the issue is occurring somewhere else in your app.

Answer (score 0):

Using `lookAt(x, y, z)` on a PerspectiveCamera will make the camera point directly towards the `x, y, z` position. With that in mind, if you want the camera to be horizontal, just provide a y value that's equal to the camera's y-position.

```js
var yHeight = 12;
camera.position.set(0, yHeight, 15);
camera.lookAt(0, yHeight, 0);
```